# What does a variable over an equals sign mean?

Tags: probability, notation

I found this notation [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.56.7448&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
[image]

I've never seen a variable written over an equals sign. What does it mean?

Comment: Most likely means distributional equality.

Comment: @StefanHansen Thanks for the reply, does that mean that $$x_{A, B}\;|\;(e_A, e_B) \overset{d}{=} x_{A, B}\;|\;a_A -d_B -\gamma \Delta_{AB}$$ is equivalent to:
$$P(x_{A, B}\;|\;(e_A, e_B)) = P(x_{A, B}\;|\;a_A -d_B -\gamma \Delta_{AB})$$

Comment: It means that the conditional distribution of $x_{A,B}$ given $(e_A,e_B)$ is the same as the conditional distribution of $x_{A,B}$ given $a_A-d_B,\gamma\Delta_{AB}$.